# Has Russia clarified what crimes it charges against the judges of the ICC?

Tags: russian-federation, international-criminal-court, extraterritoriality

[Back in September 2023](https://www.politico.eu/article/russia-international-criminal-court-icc-president-piotr-hofmanski-wanted-list/):

> Russia’s ministry of internal affairs has placed International Criminal Court (ICC) President Piotr Hofmański on its wanted list, according to the ministry’s online database.
>
> The site does not specify what Hofmański is wanted for, but it states he is “wanted under the article of the Criminal Code,” reported Russian state-run news site TASS. Alongside Hofmański, the ministry also added ICC Vice President Luz del Carmen Ibáñez Carranza and judge Bertram Schmitt to the wanted list.

Also, somewhat earlier

> Russia has placed several ICC officials on its wanted list, including British prosecutor Karim Khan and judges Tomoko Akane and Rosario Salvatore Aitala.

It's rather obvious this is a tit-for-tat measure, but anyhow, has Russia clarified what crimes [under Russian law] exactly do they charge/seek the ICC justices with/for?

Comment: (N.B. sometimes they are more explicit, like whey more recently [did the same with the Estonian PM](https://www.voanews.com/a/estonian-pm-on-russian-wanted-list-over-efforts-to-remove-soviet-era-war-memorials-/7486113.html) and [most of](https://zona.media/article/2024/02/13/wanted) the Lithuanian lawmakers--Russia charged them with "falsification of history" and the "rehabilitation of Nazism" for removing Soviet monuments.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a [different article](https://www.politico.eu/article/putin-russia-icc-criminal-case-moscow-ukraine-war/) they reported about the commencement of the criminal investigation against the ICC members. They linked to [this announcement](https://t.me/sledcom_press/5885), which lists specific sections of the criminal code:

> В действиях прокурора Международного уголовного суда содержатся признаки преступлений, предусмотренных ч. 2 ст. 299, ч. 1 ст. 30 ч. 2 ст. 360 УК РФ

and

> В действиях судей Международного уголовного суда содержатся признаки преступлений, предусмотренных ч. 2 ст. 301, ч. 1 ст. 30 ч. 2 ст. 360 УК РФ

From what I understand, the titles roughly translate to:

- [Section 299](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_10699/2e4a2d33bf614199d094494b0c0da66112176e08/) - Criminal prosecution against undoubtedly innocents,
- [Section 301](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_10699/d2764ebc80b1ed70359c06686793c7d90e93cd99/) - False imprisonment,
- [Section 360](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_10699/f968391421e9879f529cf7a1a085835ac78df52a/) - threatening or committing attacks on international officials,
- [Section 30](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_10699/da2816304405597f50919c18f77906b4bf4594c3/) - conspiracy to commit a felony.